# How to keep header from being selected when there is one item in a QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, select, header, qtablewidget

I can't seem to keep the horizontal header from being selected when I select a single row in a `QTableWidget`.

**Example:**

[image]

How can I prevent the header from being selected too? This only happens when one row is in the table. If it has more than two rows, then it works as expected and only the row itself is selected.

---

*Note: I have set*

```
ui->tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
```

*so that the entire row is selected when the user clicks a cell.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a test and observed the same behavior and I'm not sure what the intended behavior is. I was able to prevent it by setting `horizontalHeaderHighlightSections` to false but I'm not sure if that is an optimal solution.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe method [setHighlightSections()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#highlightSections-prop) can help:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setHighlightSections(false);
```